# How to made refresh-able counter?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm beginner in JS. I have animated numbers. Works good, but i want my counters refresh every time, when scrolling page down.
So fiddle:

```js
 if ($('#animated-counter').length) {
   $('#animated-counter .count').each(function() {
     $(this).prop('Counter', 0).animate({
       Counter: $(this).text()
     }, {
       duration: 4000,
       easing: 'swing',
       step: function(now) {
         $(this).text(Math.ceil(now));
       }
     });
   });
 }
```

```css
.count {
  color: #fff;
  font-size: 63px;
  font-weight: bold;
  line-height: 1.2;
  display: block;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.animated-number-caption {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-size: 23px;
}
.animated-number {
  background-color: rgba(25, 29, 32, .3);
  padding: 50px 0;
  text-align: center;
}
.animated-numbers-wrap {
  background: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(52, 168, 23, 1) 0%, rgba(46, 133, 33, 1) 100%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="match" style="height:500px;"></div>
<div id="animated-counter" class="animated-numbers-wrap">
  <div class="animated-numbers">
    <div class="animated-number"><span class="count">200</span>
      <h6><span class="animated-number-caption">Projects</span></h6>
    </div>
    <div class="animated-number"><span class="count">150</span>
      <h6><span class="animated-number-caption">Projects</span></h6>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

So i think, that it possible to make any refresh and waypoint(function(direction) and if (direction == 'down')...but i don't have any ideas. Help me please!

Comment: You would definitely need waypoints in here. Which could simply be a div with an id placed at the start of these counting areas. What you would do is check on window scroll for the position of the screen and if that position matched up with your waypoint then you would call .stop() on the animating counter, reset its text, and then call your original animation.